# Problems with booking site. Cannot remove taken hours

Tags: python, django

I started building my first website with Django.
Trying to create website for my girlfriend`s bussines(manicure salon), and have some problems.
First problem was booking form, and picking free hours.
Managed to find solution with 2 models and OneToOne relation:

```
class FreeHoursModel(models.Model):
    EARLY = '10:00'
    MID = '13:00'
    LATE = '16:00'

    HOURS = [(x, x) for x in (EARLY, MID, LATE)]

    time = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=HOURS,
        default=1,
    )
    date = models.DateField(
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{str(self.date)} - {self.time}"


class Customer(models.Model):
    MAX_LENGTH = 25
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_LENGTH,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_LENGTH,
    )
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    date_of_booking = models.DateField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    hours = models.OneToOneField(
        FreeHoursModel,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'date_of_booking'
```

Second problem is how to remove taken hours.

These are my views:

```
class IndexView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'landing_page/landing_page.html'


class BookingView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'booking_page/booking.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('summary')
    form_class = CustomerForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        hour = str(form.cleaned_data['hours'])

        # print(hour.encode("utf-8"))
        return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.success_url:
            return self.success_url
        return super().get_success_url()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['customer'] = CustomerForm()

        return context


class SummaryView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'booking_page/summary.html'

    # if Customer.objects.all():
    #     latest_created_booking = Customer.objects.latest()
    #     latest_taken_hour_id = latest_created_booking.hours_id
    #     latest_taken_hour = FreeHoursModel.objects.filter(id=latest_taken_hour_id)[0]
    #     print(latest_taken_hour)
    #     latest_taken_hour.delete()


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    return context
```

I tried to delete db entity of hour related with latest created Customer entity

```
    # if Customer.objects.all():
    #     latest_created_booking = Customer.objects.latest()
    #     latest_taken_hour_id = latest_created_booking.hours_id
    #     latest_taken_hour = FreeHoursModel.objects.filter(id=latest_taken_hour_id)[0]
    #     print(latest_taken_hour)
    #     latest_taken_hour.delete()
```

in view that is for succes_url. But this delete last entity only when run project, not when hit SummaryView.
Please help with any suggestions

Comment: Can you explain more about the free hours. What does it mean? How exactly is it supposed to work?

Comment: This model is used in booking form . Hours are added from admin menu, and customer picks can pick from dropdown menu with available hours. That was my solution to problem number one.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want the customer to choose only from the specified times (10,13,16 o'clock)? And, why would you want to delete the last booked time? Is it so it should be free for another customer to book it?

Comment: i want to delete entity for selected date , thats why model has 2 fields date and hour

Comment: What's the purpose of deleting the selected hours?

Comment: Entity looks like this: 2023-10-15 10:00. There will be only one customer per hour.  3hours and 3 customers per day. I am trying to delete hour from db, after is taken.If 1 custilomer takes 13:00 next customer to have only 2 choices 10:00 and 16:00. My approach may be wrong from start. If You have any suggestions,  please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach the problem.
First, I would create three models:

- `Customer`: Responsible for holding customer information.
- `WorkHours`: Hours during the day we are available for booking
- `Booking`: To holding booking information.

This will also mean I would create two views:

- `CreateCustomerView`: For creating a customer.
- `CreateBookingView`: To create a booking.

The flow will be:

1. Let the customer enter their personal details in the `CreateCustomerView`.
2. If setp 1 is successful, redirect the customer to the `CreateBookingView` where they will book an appointment.
3. If step 2 is successful, redirect to the `SummaryView`.

I would also use Django's `ModelForm` to make form creation and data saving easier.

So, here is my sample code:

**models.py**
Of note is the `unique_together` attribute in the `Meta` class of the `Booking` model. This is to ensure that no `hour` and `date` are the same. So, if one customer books an appointment at '16:00' today, no other customer will be able to book it. But if they book the same `hour` tomorrow, they will be allowed to since tomorrow will be free.

```py
from django.utils import timezone

def free_hours():
    return [(i, i) for i in "10:00,13:00,16:00".split(",")]

class WorkHour(models.Model):
    hour = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=free_hours()) # choices can also receive functions that return a sequence object. 

class Customer(models.Model):
    # customer fields: first/last_name, phone_no, etc.


class Booking(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date)
    hour = models.ForeignKey(WorkHour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["date", "hour"]
```

**forms.py**
I am excluding `customer` field on the `Booking` model because the customer will be set in the view later.

```py
from django import forms

class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        exclude = ["customer]

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views**
When I am working with Class-Based Views, I like to inherit from base `View`, and my logic in the respective request methods. I find this easier with less abstraction present in `edit` views like `FormView`, `CreateView`.

Please note:

- `CreateBookingView` is accepting a `user_pk` argument, which is being sent by the `CreateCustomerView`. It is being used to fetch and set the customer for this booking.

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse

class CreateCustomerView(View):
    template_name = "customer_page/create.html"
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CustomerForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            customer = form.save()
            return redirect("create-booking", kwargs={"user_pk": customer.pk})
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

class CreateBookingView(View):
    template_name = "booking_page/booking.html"
    def get(self, request, user_pk, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BookingForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
    
    def post(self, request, user_pk, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            booking = form.save(commit=True)
            booking.customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
            booking.save()
            return reverse("summary")
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

**urls**
Nothing strange here, I hope it's self-explanatory.

```py
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/customer/", CreateCustomerView.as_view(), name="create-customer"),
    path("user/<int:user_pk>/book/", CreateBookingView.as_view(), name="create-booking"),
    
]
```

This basic setup should work fine. You may wish improve the user experience in some parts. Like for example, in the BookingView, you can only show `free hours` that are available for the date that the customer selects. It can be a good exercise, perhaps needing some JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for help @McPherson. I'll try this method.